# How to upload towerjs assets to S3?

Tags: towerjs

What is the right way to upload production assets to S3 in towerjs?
I have my S3 credentials configured in config/credentials.coffee

Then I try *cake assets:publish*

and get

```
        /Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/Cakefile:15
    client = knox.createClient(Tower.secrets.s3);
                                            ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 's3' of undefined
    at Object._this [as action] (/Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/Cakefile:15:45)
    at helpers.extend.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:42:26)
    at Object.action (/Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/Cakefile:9:12)
    at helpers.extend.invoke (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:42:26)
    at Object.exports.run (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/cake.js:67:21)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/bin/cake:7:38)
    at Module._compile (module.js:449:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:467:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
```

UPDATE: I figured out that the right line in the task *assets:upload:s3* should look
client  = knox.createClient Tower.config.credentials.s3

But then I get another error

```
/Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/node_modules/tower/lib/tower/server/application/assets.js:112
    _console.debug("Uploading to " + Tower.secrets.s3.bucket);
                                                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 's3' of undefined
    at Object.Tower.Application.Assets.upload (/Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/node_modules/tower/lib/tower/server/application/assets.js:112:51)
    at Object._this [as action] (/Users/avaranovich/projects/demos/node/firstApp/Cakefile:16:37)
```

Seems like Tower.secrets.s3.bucket hardcoded somewhere else.

Thanks,
Andrei

Answer (score 2):

I would hang tight, watch the development branch closely or even start contributing to its requirements as outlined in the Readme: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/tree/development

They're finally at a "feature complete" stage with the development branch and are now working on shoring it up so that bugs are resolved and performance improves.

Be sure to watch daily the quickly changing roadmap: https://github.com/viatropos/tower/blob/master/ROADMAP.md

Moving at a rather impressive rate given the limited number of developers!  We need to throw our weight behind this project.

Comment: Added the roadmap to the post. I'm impressed to see updates nearly daily or every couple of days that are really pushing us towards the .5 release which is the big one we all need to really start using this on a more serious level.